# How do nested type arguments work?

Tags: java, generics

Why does the declaration

```
Set<Set<String>> var = new HashSet<Set<String>>();
```

work but the declaration

```
Set<Set<String>> var = new HashSet<HashSet<String>>();
```

choke?

I'm aware that 'top level' (not sure if that's the correct phrase here) generics in a declaration play by different rules than those inside the pointy brackets, but I'm interested to learn the reason. Not an easy question to google, so I thought I'd try you guys.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's because you could circumvent the type system if it were allowed. The property you desire is called [covariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)). If collections were covariant then you'd be able to do this:

```
Set<Set<String>> var = new HashSet<HashSet<String>>();

var.add(new TreeSet<String>());
```

A TreeSet is a type of Set, and so static type checking would not prevent you from inserting a TreeSet into var. But var expects HashSets and HashSets only, not any old type of Set.

Personally, I always write your first declaration:

```
Set<Set<String>> var = new HashSet<Set<String>>();
```

The outer class needs to have a conrete implementation, but there's usually no need to nail down the inner class to HashSet specifically. If you create a HashSet of Sets you are good to go. Whether you then proceed to insert a series of HashSets into var is your choice later in the program, but no need to restrict the declaration.

---

For what it's worth, arrays in Java *are* covariant, unlike the collection classes. This code will compile and will throw a runtime exception instead of being caught at compile time.

```
// Arrays are covariant, assignment is permitted.
Object[] array = new String[] {"foo", "bar"};

// Runtime exception, can't convert Integer to String.
array[0] = new Integer(5);
```

Answer (score 7):

The reason is that `Set<Set<String>>` is not equivalent to `Set<HashSet<String>>`! A `Set<Set<String>>` may contain *any* type of `Set<String>`, while a `Set<HashSet<String>>` may only contain `HashSet<String>`.

If `Set<Set<String>> set = new HashSet<HashSet<String>>()` were legal, you could also do this without any error:

```
Set<HashSet<String>> setOfHashSets = new HashSet<HashSet<String>>();
Set<Set<String>> set = setOfHashSets;
set.add(new TreeSet<String>());
HashSet<String> wrong = set.iterator().next(); // ERROR!
```

It is, however, legal to use a bounded wildcard here:

```
Set<? extends Set<String>> set = setOfHashSets;
```

This is allowed because now, the type of object the set contains is `? extends Set<String>`... in other words, "some specific but *unknown* class that implements `Set<String>`". Since you don't know exactly what the specific type of `Set<String>` it is allowed to contain is, you aren't allowed to add anything to it (except `null`)... you might be wrong, leading to an error later like in my first example.

**Edit:**

Note that the "top level" generics you refer to in your question are called *parameterized types*, meaning types that take one or more *type parameters*. The reason that `Set<Set<String>> set = new HashSet<Set<String>>()` is legal is that `HashSet<T>` implements `Set<T>` and is therefore a *subtype* of `Set<T>`. Note, however, that the type parameter `T` must match! If you have another type `S` that is a subtype of `T`, a `HashSet<S>` (or just a `Set<S>` even) is not a subtype of `Set<T>`! I explained the reason for that above.

This is exactly the situation here.

```
Set<Set<String>> set = new HashSet<Set<String>>();
```

If we replace `Set<String>` with `T` here, we get `Set<T> set = new HashSet<T>()`. It's easy to see, then, that the *actual type arguments* involved match and that the type on the right side of the assignment is a subtype of the type on the left.

```
Set<Set<String>> set = new HashSet<HashSet<String>>();
```

Here we have to replace `Set<String>` and `HashSet<String>` with `T` and `S` respectively, where `S` is a subtype of `T`. With that done, we get `Set<T> set = new HashSet<S>()`. As I described above, `HashSet<S>` is not a subtype of `Set<T>`, so the assignment is illegal.

Answer (score 3):

That's because of the way the generics work in Java.

```
Set<? extends Set<String>> var = new HashSet<HashSet<String>>();
```

Comment: This answer doesn't make a lot of sense to me. John Kugelman and ColinD really illustrate the problem clearly.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with "inferring" the type parameter.

Comment: @erickson: It solves the issue at least and there were none when I posted it, so I'll leave it But I upvoted [Kugelman's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338429/generic-java-generics-question/4338535#4338535) as best answer.

Comment: @haylem: The thing is, the OP wasn't asking for anything to be "solved"... they were asking why it's like that. And this answer amounts to "it works that way because it works that way" with some code that does work but no real explanation.

Comment: This isn't a solution though.  Not really.  You're basically disallowing anything from being added to `var`.  And @ColinD: if by "work" you mean "compile" :-).

Answer (score 0):

The difference is simple, by allowing `Set<Set<String>> var = new HashSet<Set<String>>` you're allowing `var` to only accept a values of type `Set<String>` (of which `HashSet` is of `Set`).

As for `Set<Set<String>> var = new HashSet<HashSet<String>>();`, not only won't it compile, because the inner type of `var` expects `Set<String>` but it finds an `HashSet<String>`. This would mean that `var.add(new TreeSet<String>());` would be erronous (type incompatibility between `HashSet` and `TreeSet`).

Hope this helps.

Comment: `Set<? extends Set<String>>` means that the outer set can't accept anything at all except `null`, but it does contain things that are a `Set<String>`.

Comment: And, a `Set<Set<String>>` expects (if by "expects" you mean "the `add()` method *allows*") any implementor of `Set<String>`.  Set isn't even a concrete class, so it would be quite useless if a `Set<Set<String>>` didn't take subtypes of `Set<String>`.

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman: I don't understand your updated answer. You seem to suggest that the code will compile, but then again that it won't. Then you suggest that adding a `LinkedHashSet<String>` would throw a `ClassCastException`, when in fact adding a `LinkedHashSet<String>` would succeed due to the fact that a `LinkedHashSet<String>` is a subtype of `HashSet<String>`, and even if it were not there is nothing that checks that in the `add` method at runtime due to type erasure.

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman: I still don't understand what you're suggesting the problem with adding a `LinkedHashSet<String>` is supposed to be. There isn't any type incompatibility between `HashSet` and `LinkedHashSet` since a `LinkedHashSet` _is_ a `HashSet`. It's just doesn't really illustrate the dangers involved since it would work perfectly.

Comment: @ColinD, well spotted...i've used `TreeSet` now.

Answer (score 0):

Lets reduce your example to something simpler

```
//Array style valid an Integer is a Number
Number[] numArr = new Integer[10]
//Generic style invalid
List<Number> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
//Compiled (erased) List valid, pre generics (java 1.4) 
List list2 = new ArrayList();
```

The first line is the code with covariant arrays, which is legal java code. The next line contains a simple example for your problem with Lists of Integer and Number which is invalid. In the last line we have the valid and erased non generic lists.

Lets add an item to our Numbers, 1.5 seems like a reasonable number to me^^

```
//this will compile but give us a nice RuntimeException 
numArr[0] = 1.5f
//This would compile and thanks to type erasure 
//would even run without exception
list1.add(1.5f)
```

RuntimeExceptions should not happen in valid code, but numArr can only hold integers and not Numbers as one would belive. Generics catch this error at compile time as they are not covariant.

And here is the reason why these lists of Number and Integer cannot be accepted as the same. The methods provided by both Lists accept different arguments, the Integer list is more limited by only accepting Integers. This means that the interfaces provided by both Lists are not compatible.

```
List<Number>.add(Number n)
List<Integer>.add(Integer n)
```

The same is valid for your Sets

```
Set<Set<String>>.add(Set<String> s)
HashSet<HashSet<String>>.add(HashSet<String> s)
```

The add and other methods of both types are not compatible.

(second try at answer, hope i didn't mindread someone this time)